# systemd restart service on watchdog does terminate previous hanged instance

Tags: daemon, watchdog, systemd

I'm trying to setup systemd service configuration to restart service on watchdog failure. If my application does not call sd_notify() in time, systemd spawns new instance.
However, previus instance is not killed. After some time, I have many instances of my application running.

```
$ systemctl status my-daemon.service

  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/my-daemon.service; disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Tue, 26 Aug 2014 10:27:46 +0000; 7s ago
Main PID: 1433 (attendance-syst)
  CGroup: name=systemd:/system/my-daemon.service
      ├ 1281 /usr/local/bin/my-daemon
      ├ 1384 /usr/local/bin/my-daemon
      ├ 1407 /usr/local/bin/my-daemon
      └ 1433 /usr/local/bin/my-daemon
      ...
```

This is part of my service file:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my-daemon
TimeoutStopSec=5
WatchdogSec=10
Restart=on-failure
```

How can i configure systemd to kill instances which fails on watchdog?

I have already read manual [page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) but it didn't help me.

I thought `Restart=on-failure` shall restart hanged process by default...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug and it's already fixed in newer versions of systemd.

- In systemd 208 (available for debian jessie) it works correctly.
- In systemd 204 (available for debian wheezy via backports) it's still broken.

I haven't found exact release where they fixed it.